# Looking for a book where a girl wakes up in an android body after Earth is destroyed

Tags: story-identification

The novel is about a girl who wakes up in an android body after Earth is destroyed by a mysterious species who eradicate technology. The new society she finds herself in prohibits technological advances to prevent future discoveries. The story outlines her efforts to lead mankind into a new era of technological discovery beginning with black powder and sailing.

Comment: Can your recall any other details? Even something as trivial as when you read it could help.

Comment: After Earth is destroyed, she wakes up where, on a spaceship or on another planet? The new society prohibits technology to prevent future discovery — of what? That's to prevent the new society (of androids?) from being discovered by the mysterious species who destroyed the Earth? Does the prohibited technology include androids?

Comment: See OP comment confirming duplicate status below.

Answer (score 9):

I suspect you're thinking of David Webers Safehold series. The main protagonist is indeed the android replica of a woman - though she changes the android body into that of a man and changes her name to Merlin.

The world Safehold is the last known bastion of the human race, and the lack of tech is in an attempt to hide from the aliens who destroyed the rest of the human race.

Comment: That's the book/series. Thanks,